# PHP Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: linux, php, postgresql

I'm trying to launch a web site (mantisbt) work with postgresql and i'm getting this warnning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_pgsql.so' - libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pgsql.so' - libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas how to solve this ?

I'm using :

- CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
- PHP 5.3.3 (cli)
- OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips

Comment: As it's telling you it can't find the files the obvious solution would be to install those files. There is probably a package available.

Comment: it works ! thanks for the hint, i solve this by creating a symbolic link of libssl.so in /usr/lib64 `ln -s /opt/postgresql/pg95/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0`  and also `ln -s /opt/postgresql/pg95/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0`